# What is a good practice to entirely replace an existing Lucene index?

Tags: lucene, information-retrieval, master-slave

We use Lucene as a search engine. Our Lucene index is created by a master server, which is then deployed to slave instances.

This deployment is currently done by a script that deletes the files, and copy the new ones.

We needed to know if there was any good practice to do a "hot deployment" of a Lucene index. Do we need to stop or suspend Lucene? Do we need to inform Lucene the index has changed?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Lucene do you use in your environment?

Comment: Try `Solr` it has replication.

Comment: We are on 4.8.1. Don't get me wrong; the system works, I am just looking for best practice because I am not sure we are doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to open the index in **append** mode for writing. You can achieve this by calling IndexWriter with the open mode named IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND.

Once this is done, you are ready to both **update** existing documents and add new documents. For updating documents, you need to provide some kind of a unique identifier for a document (could be the URL or something else that is guaranteed to be unique). Now if you want to update a document with id say "Doc001" simply call the **updateDocument** function of Lucene passing "Doc001" as the *Term* (the very first) argument.

By this you can update an existing index without deleting it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I feel like I was not understood. I need to replace an index entirely, not document by document. Replacing the files works, I just want to make sure there is no side effect or possible issues I am not aware of.

Comment: Well, in that case simply ensure that you close all the open readers/writers to the existing index... (you can be sure of this if there's no write.lock file in the Lucene index folder)... you can then remove the entire folder with a bash script.. and then can reopen a new index writer and reader(s)...